# Multiprocessing python with multiple connections to Sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, python-multiprocessing

What I'm trying to do is to fire multiple connections to the same sqlite database (since sharing connections and cursors are not allowed according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#multithreading)).

Inside `gv.py`

```
var = None
```

Inside `test.py` ...

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import sqlite3

import gv


def create_conn(dummy):

    conn = None
    print('inside create_conn()')
    print('gv.var =', gv.var)
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(gv.var)
        conn.close()
    except sqlite3.Error:
        print('Error!')


def change_gv_var():
    gv.var = r'D:\test.db'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Start')

    print('Before calling change_gv_var()')
    print('gv.var =', gv.var)
    change_gv_var()
    print('After calling change_gv_var()')
    print('gv.var =', gv.var)

    print('\nCalling pool.map')
    pool = mp.Pool(processes = 4)
    pool.map(create_conn, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])


    print('Done')
```

Inside the `create_conn()` function, it could not fetch the value of `gv.var` in `multiprocessing.Pool`, but if I change that to a for-loop, there is no problem.

The output is shown below.

```
Start
Before calling change_gv_var()
gv.var = None
After calling change_gv_var()
gv.var = D:\test.db

Calling pool.map
inside create_conn
gv.var = None
inside create_conn
gv.var = None
inside create_conn
gv.var = None
inside create_conn
gv.var = None
inside create_conn
gv.var = None
```

Comment: Why not use multithreading instead? Multiprocessing is slightly more complex to implement and generally only better for CPU limited functions, which is unlikely to be the case for you.

Comment: @101 But why is the value of `gv.var` not fetched correctly?

Comment: This happend because of the way the pool processes are initialized on Windows. The main code of the module is re-execute in every process, the code with the `__main__` condition is not. You will see different behavior on UNIX like operating system since they are using a fork for the new processes.

Comment: In that case, what should be my approach if I were to use a common variable (whose value is to be determined at runtime)?

Comment: You can implicitly pass it to your processing function